# how to fix pagination in python query and html

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, pagination

I am having trouble implementing pagination with Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-mysql or Flask-Pagination. how to initialize the pagination. I am beginner, i'm new to Python.

```
@app.route('/chats/<string:id><int:pageno>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def chats(id, pageno=1):
   if id != 0:
     # Create cursor
     cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

     # Get message
     cur.execute(
         "SELECT count(id) as totalmessages FROM message WHERE 
         (msg_by=%s AND msg_to=%s) OR (msg_by=%s AND msg_to=%s) "
         "ORDER BY id DESC ", (id, session['uid'], session['uid'], id))
     chats = cur.fetchall()
     totalpages = math.ceil(chats.totalmessages / 20);
     if pageno > totalpages:
         pageno == totalpages
     else:
         cur.execute("SELECT * FROM message WHERE 
         (msg_by=%s AND msg_to=%s) OR (msg_by=%s AND msg_to=%s) "
         "ORDER BY id DESC limit " + ((pageno - 1) * 20) + ", 20",
                    (id, session['uid'], session['uid'], id))
         chats = cur.fetchall()
         # Close Connection
         cur.close()
         return render_template('chats.html', chats=chats)

     return redirect(url_for('login'))
   return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

i dont know where to begin. I want to query all rows of the database table, limit the results to 10 and paginate. please someone help me

Answer (score 1):

I have done it before for my blog, I used the following code with Flask-SQAlchemy.

App.py

```
@app.route('/blog', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def blog():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=9)
    return render_template('blog.html', posts=posts)
```

Now with Jinja2 in your Html file:

blog.html

```
{% for i in posts.items %}
{{i.title}}
{{ i.body }}
{% endfor %}



{% for page_num in posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}

    {% if page_num %}

    {% if posts.page == page_num %}


{{ url_for('blog', page=page_num) }} {{ page_num }}

    {% else %}

{{ url_for('blog', page=page_num) }}  {{ page_num }}

    {% endif %}

    {% else %}

    ...
    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
```

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#utilities
https://riptutorial.com/flask/example/22201/pagination-route-example-with-flask-sqlalchemy-paginate

I hope that it somehow helps you. Cheers

Comment: thanks a lot for that, please can you create also for my code please